# This statment always evaluates to true "lookahead" not working with me "regex" perl

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

The following statement always evaluates to true when given `$Error = (uint8) 0xFE +2`

```
if($Error =~ m/0x[0-9ABCDEFabcdef]+(?!\s*\+[0-9]+)/)
```

Comment: Your code `$Error = (uint8) 0xFE +2` gives me the error `Number found where operator expected at - line 1, near ") 0xFE" (Missing operator before 0xFE?)`. Because you have no quotes around your string. Please do not be sloppy with details like this when asking questions, but post exact code that you have used and tested. Anything else is to waste people's time making them draw the wrong conclusions about your problem.

Comment: Very small side note, but your character class `[0-9ABCDEFabcdef]` can be simplified to just `[0-9A-Fa-f]`.  There's also a named class for that `[[:xdigit:]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the regex engine backtracks in the characters matched by `[0-9ABCDEFabcdef]+` to succeed. To avoid this, use a possessive quantifier (that forbids backtracking for this particular part of the pattern :

```
[0-9ABCDEFabcdef]++
```

Backtracking in short:

When a pattern fails at a position in a string, the regex engine goes back character by character to try other possibilities.

With your example string:

```
 string  |  pattern                              |  state
---------+---------------------------------------+---------------
0xFE +2  |  0x[0-9ABCDEFabcdef]+(?!\s*\+[0-9]+)  | OK
0xFE +2  |  0x[0-9ABCDEFabcdef]+(?!\s*\+[0-9]+)  | OK
0xFE +2  |  0x[0-9ABCDEFabcdef]+(?!\s*\+[0-9]+)  | FAIL
0xFE +2  |  0x[0-9ABCDEFabcdef]+(?!\s*\+[0-9]+)  | BACKTRACKING
0xFE +2  |  0x[0-9ABCDEFabcdef]+(?!\s*\+[0-9]+)  | SUCCEED
```

As an aside comment, instead of `[0-9ABCDEFabcdef]`, you can use the POSIX character class `[[:xdigit:]]`.

Comment: Yes , it worked now , but could you explain what is backtrack

Comment: @user3438074: Backtracking is a *mechanism* that the regex engine uses and is irrelevant to its *effect*. What you are asking is, *"is there a substring of `$error` that matches this patterm"*. The regex finds `0xF`, which is `0x` followed by one or more hex digits, and it is followed by `E` which correctly doesn't match the negative look-ahead pattern. Job done! The `+` quantifier means "as many as possible of these *while the pattern still matches*".